# How to use stanford English Tagger in python Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, pos-tagger

I successfully run the stanford english tagger, like below:
input:
"The picture is clear"
output:

```
[[(u'This', u'DT'), (u'picture', u'NN'), (u'is', u'VBZ'), (u'clear', u'JJ')]]
```

But I want to read the whole file, and wish output is like this:

> This_DT picture_NN is_VBZ clear_JJ

Like a sentence. Not a format in brackets. But I don't know how to change it in python.

My original code

```
import nltk
from nltk.tag.stanford import POSTagger
st = POSTagger('/Users/apple/Desktop/package/stanford-postagger/models/english-left3words-distsim.tagger', '/Users/apple/Desktop/package/stanford-postagger/stanford-postagger.jar')

print st.tag('This picture is clear'.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

Fairly straightforward list/tuple/string manipulation:

```
inp = [[(u'This', u'DT'), (u'picture', u'NN'), (u'is', u'VBZ'), (u'clear', u'JJ')]]

out = []
for t in inp[0]:
    out += t

outs = "_".join(out)
print outs
```

The data you have is a list of list of tuples.  We are only interested in the first element - hence the `inp[0]`.

We iterate through this list (I could have used a list comprehension) extracting the elements of the tuple (`t`), creating another list (`out`).  It is then a simple task to `join` the elements together with an underscore to produce a string.

Comment: Thank you. I used another version of Stanford POStagger.